# advanced sql query using join

Tags: sql, database

Concepts Banking Example

```
branch (branch_name, branch_city, assets)
customer (customer_name, customer_street, customer_city)
account (account_number, branch_name, balance)
loan (loan_number, branch_name, amount)
depositor (customer_name, account_number)
borrower(customer_name, loan_number)
```

Find all customers who have an account at all branches located in Brooklyn.

```
select distinct S.customer-name 
   from depositor as S 
   where not exists (
   (select branch-name 
     from branch where branch-city = ‘Brooklyn’)
   except
   (select R.branch-name 
    from depositor as T, account as R 
    where T.account-number = R.account-number 
      and S.customer-name = T.customer-name)
   )
```

I find the following query difficult to understand. Will someone please explain the logic behind it?

Comment: That makes no sense whatsoever. I don't understand the reason for the 1st subquery, or how it relates to the second. You would just doing a simple grouping on an inner join, matching depositor to account, to branch, where branch name = brooklyn. Unless something very weird was done with the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you're selecting the `customer-name` from the `depositor` table where:

1. You're getting the `branch-name` for all branches in Brooklyn: `(select branch-name from branch where branch-city = ‘Brooklyn’)`
2. You're getting all of the `branch-name`s in Brooklyn for which that particular customer has an account at: `(select R.branch-name from depositor as T, account as R where T.account-number = R.account-number and S.customer-name = T.customer-name)`
3. You're `EXCEPT`ing (subtracting) the values in 2 from 1. For instance, if "Best branch" was in 2, it would be removed from the result of 1 (if it was also there).
4. You're expecting `NOT EXISTS` for the result of 3. That is, you expect that there will be nothing left from the subtraction in step 3. All of the branches from 1 should've also been in 2 for the customer to have his/her name printed out.

**Examples**

Suppose there were three branches in Brooklyn: "Best", "Average" and "Worst".

*Bob* goes to "Best" and "Average".

1. All branches: "Best", "Average", "Worst"
2. Branches that Bob goes to: "Best", "Average"
3. 2 - 1: "Best", "Average", "Worst" minus "Best", "Average". This leaves us only with "Worst"
4. `NOT EXISTS` - hold on a second, we still have "Worst"! Something exists! That means this condition evaluates to `false`

Bob is NOT selected.

---

*Mary* goes to "Best", only.

1. All branches: "Best", "Average", "Worst"
2. Branches that Bob goes to: "Best"
3. 2 - 1: "Best", "Average", "Worst" minus "Best". This leaves us with "Average", "Worst"
4. `NOT EXISTS` - hold on a second, we still have "Average" and "Worst"! Something exists! That means this condition evaluates to `false`

Mary is NOT selected.

---

*Busy person* goes to "Best", "Average" and "Worst".

1. All branches: "Best", "Average", "Worst"
2. Branches that Bob goes to: "Best" "Average", "Worst"
3. 2 - 1: "Best", "Average", "Worst" minus "Best", "Average", "Worst". This leaves us with... nothing
4. `NOT EXISTS` - that's right! I mean.. that's `true`! Nothing exists

Busy person **is** selected.

Answer (score 2):

Note: it will probably be easier to understand queries if format them so they read more easily.

```
-- get the unique customer names
select distinct S.[customer-name] 
--from all all depositors
    from depositor as S 
--where there the are no brooklyn branches that don't have an account for that customer
    where not exists (
    --get all brooklyn branches
    (select [branch-name]
        from branch where [branch-city] = 'Brooklyn')
    except --except removes from the set above anything in the set below
    --get all brooklyn branches that have an account for the correlated depositor
    (select R.branch-name 
        from depositor as T
        , account as R 
       where
        --this is the join condition which I would prefer to see written as ON rather than put in the WHERE 
            T.[account-number] = R.[account-number] 
        --this correlates the subsquery to the depositor
        and S.[customer-name] = T.[customer-name])
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's break this query down. First of all imagine that you have `foreach loop`:

1.
I.e. imagine that big subquery is executed in loop for each customer.

```
select distinct S.customer-name from depositor as S
```

2.
Here you are selecting all branches in Brooklyn:

```
SELECT   branch - name
FROM     branch
WHERE    branch - city = ‘Brooklyn’
```

3.
And here you are selecting all branches for particular customer in loop 1. It is correlated subquery. Notice `S.customer`.

```
SELECT   R.branch - name
FROM     depositor AS T ,
        account AS R
WHERE    T.account - number = R.account - number
        AND S.customer - name = T.customer - name
```

Now `EXCEPT` will do the following: it will take each row from 2 and check if it exists in 3. If it exists it will throw it out from result. So actually if all row from 2 are thrown out it means that all branches from Brooklyn are thrown out because each has corresponding row in 3. This means that if customer has acounts in all branches he will get empty set in the subquery. The outer loop will filter out customers for which inner subquery return at least one row meaning that the customer has no account in at least one branch.